# Blocking CountDownTimer

Tags: android

i have a problem with the following code :

```
@Override
     public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        // check sensor type
         if(started){
            if(event.sensor.getType()==Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER){

                //get sensorevents + time
                outputX.setText("acclaration x:"+Float.toString(event.values[0]));
                outputY.setText("acclaration y:"+Float.toString(event.values[1]));
                outputZ.setText("acclaration z:"+Float.toString(event.values[2]));
                long currentDateTime = System.currentTimeMillis(); //getting current time of updating 

                outputT.setText("Current Time:"+df.format(currentDateTime));

             /* create class object
                gps = new GPSTracker(MainActivity.this);



                    double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                    double longitude = gps.getLongitude();

                    LatList.add(latitude);
                    LongList.add(longitude);

                    Lat.setText("Lat:"+Double.toString(latitude));

                    */


                //fill up the array 
                sensorDataTime.add(df.format(currentDateTime));
                sensorDataAx.add(event.values[0]);
                sensorDataAy.add(event.values[1]);
                sensorDataAz.add(event.values[2]);



                //for test driving play around with progressbars
                if(event.values[0]>=Math.abs(3)){ barX.setProgress(100);} 
                else if(event.values[0]>=Math.abs(2)){barX.setProgress(50);}
                else {barX.setProgress(10);}

                if(event.values[2]>=Math.abs(3)){ barY.setProgress(100);}
                else if(event.values[2]>=Math.abs(2)){barY.setProgress(50);}
                else {barY.setProgress(10);}


            }
            }





            if((event.values[0]>=3) && (mCountDown==null))

            {   //check for boundaries in x direction of kammscheKreis
                try{

                    mCountDown = new CountDownTimer(5000, 1000) { // 5000 = 5 sec, here starts the timer for 5 secs 

                         public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                             pic.setImageResource(R.drawable.stern); //setting image to beer 
                             Action.setText("Du hast zu schnell gebremst!!!");


                         }

                         public void onFinish() {
                            pic.setImageResource(0); // set the image to "transparent"
                            Action.setText(0);

                         }
                    }.start();


                    }

                    catch(Exception e){Toast.makeText(this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}}

            else if(event.values[0]<(-3) && (mCountDown2==null))
            {   
                try{

                     mCountDown2 = new CountDownTimer(5000, 1000) { // 5000 = 5 sec, here starts the timer for 5 secs 

                         public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                             pic.setImageResource(R.drawable.speedview); //setting image to speedview
                             Action.setText("Du beschleunigst zu krass!!!!");


                         }

                         public void onFinish() {
                            pic.setImageResource(0); // set the image to "transparent"
                            Action.setText(0);

                         }
                    }.start();
                }
                catch(Exception e){Toast.makeText(this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}}

        }
```

i intialize my countdowntimers as public, so what i want is to block the countdowntimer  if an event occur, so that in this 5 seconds no new event can occur. but it doesnt work. maybe the countdowntimer is never equal null ?

Comment: Please format the text.

Comment: which text shoud i format ?

Comment: Your code snippet is malformatted. If it stays that way, nobody will try to help you, becuase they can't read it.

Comment: is it now readable ??